# OpenID being outdated and using python 2 code

Tags: python, django, authentication, oauth-2.0

I have a Django project and discord OAuth2 requires openID for some reason and it automatically got installed among some packages, now when I try to run the server I always get type errors and such from the package file because OpenID uses Python 2, I tried to uninstall but it says the package isn't installed, I tried to upgrade but it said I have the latest version, also when I tried to delete the openID folder in packages of my virtual environment the auth thing doesn't work and gives an error...

Of course, it would be a pain to update the syntax manually to python 3.